# Pass mysql table values to Javascript via PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am trying to take all of the rows MYSQL table and ultimately have them end up in an interactive HTML table. I currently have no problem inserting values into my table using a $.post function, I just cannot return them, at least, not all of them.

Here is my JS code:

```
function load() {   

            $.post(
            "Returnsmedb.php",
            function (response) {
                var firstname = response.fname;
                var lastname = response.lname;
                var username = response.uname;
                var email = response.email;
                var password = response.password;

                console.log(response);
            }, 'JSON'
        );  
    }
```

PHP:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "SME";
$password = "mypass";
$db = "p3";

// Create connection
$conn =  new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$sql = "SELECT * FROM pendingusers";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$response = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

 while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    // $response[] = $row[];
    $response['fname'] = $row["fname"];
    $response['lname'] = $row["lname"];
    $response['uname'] = $row["uname"];
    $response['email'] = $row["email"];

}
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

I am thinking the easiest thing to do would be to store each row in an array, but I am not sure. It currently returns my $response array, but all of the values are null, except for 'email', which has the correct value, but it is from the last row of my DB table. Also, it only returns one row.

Any help / guidance would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just echo json_encode($result->fetch_array())

Comment: It returns one row because you overwrite `$response` on each iteration.

Comment: and the values could be null because the column names are not accurate. try using print_r($result->fetch_array()) so that you see what you get in results (or check in your database schema)

Comment: `$response[] = $row[];` was almost correct. Try `$response[] = $row;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that in this loop:

```
 while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    // $response[] = $row[];
    $response['fname'] = $row["fname"];
    $response['lname'] = $row["lname"];
    $response['uname'] = $row["uname"];
    $response['email'] = $row["email"];    
}
```

You keep overwriting the same keys in `$response`, so at the end of the loop, only the values from the last DB row will be found. you could fix this by doing

```
 while($row = $result->fetch_array()) $response[] = $row;
```

However if you'll be capturing all results, there is no need to loop through them. Just use [fetch_all](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) and you will get the full table right away.

```
 $response = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)
```

As a sidenote, I would be really careful about sending everything unfiltered from your DB to the browser like this.  Consider at least adding a `LIMIT` clause to your query so that if your table has thousands of rows, everything doesn't get sent:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM pendingusers LIMIT 50";
```

Finally, be explicit about the columns you want, so that you don't leak unwanted information if your DB gets new sensitive columns in the future

```
 $cols = 'fname, lname, uname, email';
 $sql = "SELECT $cols FROM pendingusers LIMIT 50";
```

Comment: This seems to be working, thanks! When I display $response in the console.log, each row is called object. Is there a way where I name each row uniquely? Ultimately, the table that this data will go in needs to be editable. The table is going to be for an admin to grant access to the website. I am thinking two checkboxes would be on each row to either deny the user request and or approve, each of which would perform different functions with the data from that row.